# WildFly JMS error: does not have permission='CONSUME' for queue jms.queue.exampleQueue

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jms, activemq-artemis

I am using WildFly 19 and a JMS application. After running this program it gives bellow error:

```
AMQ229213: User: murad does not have permission='CONSUME' for queue jms.queue.exampleQueue on address jms.queue.exampleQueue.jms.queue.exampleQueue
```

Here is my JMS code  :

```java
try {
    // Set up the namingContext for the JNDI lookup
    final Properties env = new Properties();
    env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.wildfly.naming.client.WildFlyInitialContextFactory");
    env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "http-remoting://127.0.0.1:8080");
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "murad");
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "Murad@1234");
    env.put("jboss.naming.client.ejb.context", true);
    namingContext = new InitialContext(env);

    ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = (ConnectionFactory) namingContext.lookup("jms/RemoteConnectionFactory");
    System.out.println("Got ConnectionFactory " + connectionFactory);

    Destination destination = (Destination) namingContext.lookup("jms/queue/exampleQueue");
    System.out.println("Got JMS Endpoint " + destination);

    // Create the JMS context
    context = connectionFactory.createContext("murad", "Murad@1234"); 
    
    JMSConsumer consumer = context.createConsumer(destination);
    // Then receive the same number of messages that were sent

    String text = consumer.receiveBody(String.class, 5000);
    if (text == null)
        System.out.println("No message Received! Maybe another Consumer listening on the Queue ??");
    System.out.println("Received message with content " + text);
} catch (Exception e) {
    ...
}
```

WildFly configuration xml is :

[image: s]

Comment: Have you given the role to which the user `murad` belongs permission to consume messages from the queue `jms.queue.exampleQueue`? Please provide your WildFly configuration XML.

Comment: I have added "murad" user as application user from wildfy addUser.bat . But Can not give permission for consume .  here is my wildfy jms configuration

Comment: Add the requested information _to the question_. Thanks!

Comment: Why can you "not give permission for consume"? If you can give permission then your application won't be able to consume messages.

Comment: This is the problem , I have no idea for giving permission for wildfy jms queue consume .How can i give permission for this scenario ?

Comment: You configure permissions using the `security-setting` block. You've already got two entries - one for the `guest` role and one for the `murad` role. However, it's not clear if the _user_ `murad` is in either of these roles. Please elaborate on how you created the user `murad` and what role you assigned to it during creation.

Comment: @JustinBertram , Yes, I have some problem in my application-roles.properties  . After resolve this one by the following way then this permission issue is overcome . i have solve here after after modify this file : "murad=guest"  .

Comment: @JustinBertram , after resolve this permission issue , i have found another one issue .I have found null  value result  from consumer.receiveBody(String.class, 5000);

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this issue after updating `applicaton-roles.properties` to use `murad=guest` (i.e. assigning the `guest` role to the user `murad`).